# Get Notification When a Particular File is Pushed to Git

Tags: git

We have a small number of files that should only be changed with the knowledge of the Tech Lead and Architect. As there is a flood of changes going to quite a number of repos, changes like this are easy to miss and developers occasionally make mistakes and check in changes to these files.

Is there a way to setup notifications on particular files in git. Note: as we have repos hosted at both Github and in our env, we are looking for a Git-based solution, not a Github specific solution.

Comment: So you just want a git post-receive hook that checks the files commited?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: @Ordous Yes, that looks like exactly what we need. Thanks!